# Swapping subscription plan gives error "Call to a member function asStripeCustomer() on null" [Laravel Cashier]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cashier

While trying to swap plans on a subscription, Laravel returns this error:

`Call to a member function asStripeCustomer() on null`

This is the code it references in the stack trace:

`$tenant->subscription('main')->swap('plan_xxxxxxxxx');`

The only implementation difference between my code and the Laravel docs is I use my own `tenant` model, rather than the default `user` model. I made sure to add the `Billable` model to my tenant model, as well as change `user_id` to `tenant_id` in the subscriptions table.

The complete stack trace is as follows:

```
[2018-12-16 22:21:27] local.ERROR: Call to a member function asStripeCustomer() on null {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function asStripeCustomer() on null at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Subscription.php:407)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Subscription.php(251): Laravel\\Cashier\\Subscription->asStripeSubscription()
#1 /var/www/html/project/app/Http/Controllers/BillingController.php(103): Laravel\\Cashier\\Subscription->swap('plan_xxxxxxxx...')
#2 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\BillingController->UpdatePlan(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#3 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('UpdatePlan', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(212): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\BillingController), 'UpdatePlan')
#6 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(169): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#7 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(679): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#8 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#10 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#11 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(75): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#13 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(681): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#29 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(656): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(622): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#31 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(611): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 /var/www/html/project/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#48 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#50 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#51 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 /var/www/html/project/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#53 {main}
```

Any help would be welcome. Thanks.

## Edit

As requested, here is the relevant methods from Laravel Cashier.

```
public function swap($plan)
{
    $subscription = $this->asStripeSubscription();

    $subscription->plan = $plan;

    $subscription->prorate = $this->prorate;

    $subscription->cancel_at_period_end = false;

    if (! is_null($this->billingCycleAnchor)) {
        $subscription->billing_cycle_anchor = $this->billingCycleAnchor;
    }

    // If no specific trial end date has been set, the default behavior should be
    // to maintain the current trial state, whether that is "active" or to run
    // the swap out with the exact number of days left on this current plan.
    if ($this->onTrial()) {
        $subscription->trial_end = $this->trial_ends_at->getTimestamp();
    } else {
        $subscription->trial_end = 'now';
    }

    // Again, if no explicit quantity was set, the default behaviors should be to
    // maintain the current quantity onto the new plan. This is a sensible one
    // that should be the expected behavior for most developers with Stripe.
    if ($this->quantity) {
        $subscription->quantity = $this->quantity;
    }

    $subscription->save();

    $this->user->invoice();

    $this->fill([
        'stripe_plan' => $plan,
        'ends_at' => null,
    ])->save();

    return $this;
}

public function asStripeSubscription()
{                         
    $subscriptions = $this->user->asStripeCustomer()->subscriptions;

    if (! $subscriptions) {
        throw new LogicException('The Stripe customer does not have any subscriptions.');
    }

    return $subscriptions->retrieve($this->stripe_id);
}
```

## Edit 2

It looks like the `user` attribute is returning null in the `asStripeSubscription` function.

Comment: Get rid of the stack trace and show us the code for the `$tenant->subscription()` method. It looks like that is returning `null`.

Comment: @lufc Updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you posted, `$this->user` is returning null. You mentioned you changed the default user to tenant, including the database field. These changes alone would cause the default user relationship on the `Subscription` model to not work anymore.

A quick look at the code shows that you also need to either set the `services.stripe.model` configuration value to your `Tenant` model, or set the `STRIPE_MODEL` environment variable in your `.env` to your `Tenant` model.

Comment: Thanks a ton! For people seeing this later, I used `php artisan config:clear` to apply changed .env file.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me: 
- modify Sunscription.php line 391 from this;

`$this->fill([`

`'stripe_plan' => $plan,`

`'ends_at' => null,`

`])->save();`

To this:

`$this->fill([`

`'name' => $plan,`

`'stripe_plan' => $plan,`

`'ends_at' => null,`

`])->save();`

and that should update your plans accordingly.